# Difficulty in making a Symbol Table for my Lexical Analyzer in Python?

Tags: python, analyzer, symbol-table, lexical

So I'm making a Lexical Analyzer as a personal project but I'm having trouble tryna build it's symbol table as I'm fairly a beginner to this language, so far I've managed to make a simple LA but without Symbol Table to insert and retrieve tokens

```
import re    #Regular Expression

token_pair = [] 
with open('SourceCodeForTesting.cpp', "r") as Source_Code:
   for line in Source_Code:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in ['str', 'int', 'bool', 'float']: 
                token_pair.append([word , 'DATATYPE'])
            elif re.match("[a-z]", word) or re.match("[A-Z]", word):
                token_pair.append([word , 'IDENTIFIER'])

            elif word in '*-/+%=""':
                token_pair.append([word ,'OPERATOR'])

            elif word in '(':
                    token_pair.append([word ,'Left Parenthesis']) 

            elif word in ')':
                    token_pair.append([word ,'Right Parenthesis'])
            elif word in '{':
                    token_pair.append([word ,'Left Curly Bracket']) 

            elif word in '}':
                    token_pair.append([word ,'Right Curly Bracket'])


            elif re.match(".[0-9]", word):
                    if word[len(word) - 1] == ';': 
                        token_pair.append([ word[:-1] , 'INTEGER'])
                        token_pair.append([';' , 'END_STATEMENT'])

            else: 
                token_pair.append([word , 'Others'])

print(token_pair)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  What specific problem are you running into when you execute your code?

Comment: @AmirAfghani I cant figure out how to make the Symbol table and store the token pairs generated from this to there

Comment: Please try and use a `dict` datatype if possible. Most of the `elif` statements can be avoided. For the `dict` the actual symbol will be the key and the corresponding word will be the value. For example `la_dict = {'*-/+%=""': 'OPERATOR', '(': 'Left Parenthesis'}`